# How to generate a log file from a Unity WebGL build?

Tags: unity, c#, debugging

I want to create a log file for every time my WebGL game is played and have the errors and warnings with detail in there. I know how to make the log file I just don't know how to get the errors and warnings and their details, and I want to have the line number too.

The only way I know of getting an error is by Try Catch but that is not working in Unity or at least in WebGL build. [The manual states that the log is output to the browser's JavaScript console](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html), but I don't have access to all of my play testers and sometimes I can't reproduce the bugs they report.

Comment: If you don't want to get downvoted I would recommend to post your current code :)

Comment: I don't have any.

Comment: Have you checked Unity's manual for log files? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html

Comment: "WebGL
On WebGL, log output is written to the browser’s JavaScript console." This is all it says, @n_palum is what I'm trying to do, impossible?

Comment: @TobiasW my current code is about 20 to 30 scripts and each of them have nearly 1000 line of code and none of them relevant to what I'm asking about. if that's ok I post some of them and confuse everyone that is reading this post.

Comment: Perhaps this question is just simply *too broad*? It is also difficult to tell if your trying to write this as a *compiler*. Some of the actions you reference (eg. knowing the specific line number) sound more like *compiler* functions.

Comment: @Gnemlock I'm not trying to write this as a compiler, as I said I need this in WebGL so it cannot be a compiler or editor script, and I need as much information as I can get, if the line of code is not possible, then it is not possible, I don't insist on that.

Comment: However you found out how to make your log files, I suggest continuing to explore there for how to add specifically what you want to it since Unity just provides log files by default - that link shows you where those are located. Maybe check those and see if they're there and have what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a WebGL game, you're running it in a web page.

You can edit the HTML to add an extra bit of JavaScript to intercept the browser's console log before your Unity game loads and tries to use it, as detailed in these StackOverflow answers by [Denys Séguret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846078/how-to-read-from-chromes-console-in-javascript) and [OneOfOne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905393/is-there-a-way-to-read-the-console-log-using-javascript).

```
var store = [];
var oldf = console.log;
console.log = function(){
   store.push(arguments);
   oldf.apply(console, arguments);
}
```

This will let you catch everything Unity would output, even if it's not coming from one of your own scripts that you can wrap in a try...catch. [Don't forget to enable exception support as described in this article from the Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-debugging.html), as it's limited by default in WebGL builds.

Once the game ends (or encounters a problem) you can have your script bundle up the contents of its `store` array into a log file to save or transmit. You can also do this periodically in case of an unexpected shutdown, and so you don't add delays when the player is trying to navigate away or close the tab.